Can Cloudflare detect that i read response body twice?
I'm building a Chrome extension. I need to intercept requests to a specific endpoint to get the response body and use the response in the extension (all ok, no malicious software)
To do that I overwrite window.fetch function with code:
const originalFetch = window.fetch;

window.fetch = async function (...args) {
  const response = await originalFetch(...args);
  const request = args[0];
  const url = request instanceof Request ? request.url : request instanceof URL ? request.href : request;

  if (url.includes('api/search')) {
    const data = await response.clone().json();

    if (data.myInfo) {
      window.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('OnMyInfoLoaded', {
          detail: {
            myInfo: data.myInfo,
          },
        }),
      );
    }
  }

  return response;
};

This script is injected in manifest:
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://external-website.com/*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "dist/injectCustomFetch.bundle.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }

In 99% cases requests to search works and I get the data, but sometimes I get 403 forbidden from server. The server uses cloudflare so I assume cloudflare somehow detects that fetch is patched? I can't access server logs/cloudflare logs as I'm not the owner of the server
This error is hard to catch too as most of the time it works fine, with occasional 403 and I don't see any pattern

No, the server doesn't care about fetch being patched. You can verify it by comparing the outgoing headers in WireShark/Fiddler/Charles or in chrome://net-export
